# Fill data from another table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, create-table

I'm wondering how to achieve this:
Given Table A and B

Table A

```
id | name
1  | Alex
2  | Bob
3  | Cindy
```

Table B

```
scene_id | name
1        | Alex
2        | Alex
3        | Cindy
4        | Bob
5        | Cindy
6        | Alex
```

Update Table B by adding a column so that it looks like:
Table B'

```
scene_id | name  | id
1        | Alex  | 1
2        | Alex  | 1
3        | Cindy | 3
4        | Bob   | 2
5        | Cindy | 3
6        | Alex  | 1
```

May I know how to code this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
alter table tableb add column id int;

update tableb b
inner join tablea a on a.name = b.name
set b.id = a.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70fc5d4acc0619f7e40268a08092c0e6)**:

```
scene_id | name  | id
-------: | :---- | -:
       1 | Alex  |  1
       2 | Alex  |  1
       3 | Cindy |  3
       4 | Bob   |  2
       5 | Cindy |  3
       6 | Alex  |  1
```